# How to declare an array of different types in a Mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a Mongoose schema which contains a field that should be an array that contains different types/objects.

For example:

```
myArrayField: [
 { type: 'type1', type1Property: 'blabla', type1Property2: 'blabla'},
 { type: 'type2', type2Property2: 'blablo' }
]
```

I have taken a look at discriminators without any success and I have found mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed. However, Mixed seems to be very open in terms that Mongo will not check anything about it. I would like to know if I can specify the different types the array can have, something like:

```
myArrayField: [ SchemaType1, SchemaType2]
```

So items can follow SchemaType1 OR SchemaType2.

Thank you in advance and regards

Comment: Did you try using a Mongoose data type called "mixed"?

Comment: @prasad_ I am aware of Mixed as I mentioned in my original question. However, Mongo will not  check anything about it and I am wondering if there is a better solution

Comment: Its possible with [MongoDB Schema Validation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/core/schema-validation/).

Comment: I am looking at it, do you know how make sure no extra properties are saved? e.g. if array element is type2, only has type2Property2 and nothing else like type1Property1 field or a random field.

Comment: In the `$jsonSchema` you can specify the required fields. You can use validation keyword "anyOf" to define two types and apply one. That means, you can have two different types of nested documents within the array. And MongoDB validates for one of the types (type1 with two fields, fld1 and fld2, and type2 with fields fld1, fld2 and fld3). But, if you also have a fld9 along with the required fields validation passes (that is your random field can be inserted). There is also an option "additionalProperties: false""- I am not sure it works the way you are looking for (in this case).

Comment: Actually, you have now open a new door for me because I usually use json schemas for API validation. So I was not aware at all you could pass a $jsonSchema to MongoDB, that would make me not to duplicate stuff, so thank you! Do you know if $jsonSchema can be used with Mongoose? I have checked the docs and I do not see anything

Comment: Meanwhile, I think I can make it work the way you perceive. But, it will require a small design change in your data structure - introduce an identifier for each type of document in the array. E.g., the new field would be `doc_type` with values either `1` or `2`. Obviously, when the value is 1, there can be only two specified fields, and when the value is 2 there will be three specified fields.

Comment: I don't know if Mongoose schema and MongoDB Schema Validation work - when used together. Mongoose is a _layer_ on the native driver. Schema Validation is applied on the database server. So, it may work.

Comment: The `doc_type` from my previous comment can be your `type` field.

Comment: Yes, so far I have made a validation field which check what type of element in the array is. However, I do not really know how can I check that element type 2 only has Type2Property1. Like I can check if (element.type2 === 'type2' && element.Type2Property1) but I do not know how to check it does not have EXTRA

Comment: With Schema Validation you can use the keyword option "additionalProperties: false". This will _not_ allow any EXTRA fields.

Comment: As far as I am aware "additionalProperties" is a json schema keyword, it cannot be used within a mongoose validator function

Comment: I am only talking about using `$jsonSchema` with Schema Validation.

Answer (score 0):

Only one type can be assigned to a field. May be you should create one schema with two fields that has different types and `required` attributes are set to false which is default.